# creating a loop that modifies directory dates

Tags: c#, loops, recursion

I'm trying to setup a loop that modifies the dates for all the directories in `@"C:\testFolder"` The code I have so far is pasted below, any help is appreciated.

```
 static void Main()
{
    string n = @"C:\testFolder";
    DateTime dtime1 = new DateTime(2015, 1, 3);

    if (Directory.Exists(n))
        Directory.SetCreationTime(n, dtime1);
        Directory.SetLastWriteTime(n, dtime1);

        Console.WriteLine("Done");

}
```

Comment: And the problem would be......

Comment: It appears to be trying to change the time stamp for "test folder", when I'm trying to change the dates for all the directories inside "test folder". The program crashes and I get an "IOException was handled - The process cannot access the file c:\testFolder because it is being used by another process. @SamAxe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `if` statement without braces will only apply to the statement immediately after it. Make sure to surround the whole block with braces.

Also, you can use `Directory.GetAllDirectories(..)` with `SearchOption` to specify that you want all directories underneath the `testFolder` *recursively*. The following shows this, but you can also use `SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly` if that's what you want instead.

```
static void Main()
{
    string n = @"C:\testFolder";
    DateTime dtime1 = new DateTime(2015, 1, 3);

    if (Directory.Exists(n)) {
        string[] allSubDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(n, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        foreach(var dir in allSubDirectories) {
            Directory.SetCreationTime(n, dtime1);
            Directory.SetLastWriteTime(n, dtime1);
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Done");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the date for all directories inside that directory you can do:

```
 static void Main()
{
    string n = @"C:\testFolder";
    DateTime dtime1 = new DateTime(2015, 1, 3);

    if (Directory.Exists(n))
    {
         Directory.SetCreationTime(n, dtime1);
         Directory.SetLastWriteTime(n, dtime1);
         var directories = Directory.GetDirectories(n);

         foreach(directory in directories)
         {
              Directory.SetCreationTime(directory , dtime1);
              Directory.SetLastWriteTime(directory , dtime1);
         }

    }
    Console.WriteLine("Done");

}
```